# Converting this to shared pointer and passing it as an argument to another C++ class

Tags: c++, pointers, arguments, this

I am working on a code with the following framework:

```
class IFirstStep // abstract interface
{
public:
    virtual commonMethod1() = 0;
    ...
};

class FirstStepBase : public IFirstStep // Jobs common to all FirstStep's
{
public:
    FirstStepBase() {}
    commonMethod1() override;
    ...
protected:
    CommonMembers;
    void correctSettings()
    {
        somePreparations;
        auto smartPtr = static_cast<std::shared_ptr<IFirstStep>>(this);
        SecondStep secondStep(smartPtr);
        some calculations using secondStep;
        reassignment of some of commonMembers;
    }
};

class FirstStep1 : public FirstStepBase
{
public:
    FirstSiep1(bool fineTune)
    {
        commonMembers = initilizeSettings();
        if (fineTune)
            correctSettings();
    }
private:
    CommonMembers initilizeSettings() {calculate and assign commonMembers;}
};

class FirstStep2 : public FirstStepBase
...
class FirstStepN : public FirstStepBase
...

class SecondStep
{
public:
    SecondStep(std::shared_ptr<IFirstStep> & firstStep) : m_firstStep(firstStep) {}
    some methods which use firstStep and return some results;
    firstStep itself is not changed;
};
```

correctSettings() is perfectly executed correcting all settings for FirstStep1 right, but crashes in MS VS debugger on exit from correctSettings() with the diagnostics:

```
File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
Line: 888
Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(block)
```

Looks the problem is caused by casting - code crashes even if exit is carried out just after the casting. Other types of casting, including pointer casts, were not accepted by the MS VS compiler. However, the thing works flawlessly if correctSettings() is changed as follows and an appropriate constructor is added to FirstStepBase

```
void correctSettings()
{
    std::shared_ptr<IFirstStep> smartPtr 
        = <std::make_shared<FirstStepBase>>(commonMembers);
    SecondStep secondStep(smartPtr);
    some calculations using secondStep;
    reassignment of some of commonMembers;
}
```

I would greatly appreciate an explanation of why the first approach fails and is it possible at all to utilize in the code this pointer rather than to generate an additional FirstStepBase object? Please, assume that there is no possibility to change interface to the SecondStep.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In your first approach, your `this` is just a raw pointer, but you tried to cast it into a `shared_pointer, which has different size, different structure.

To solve this, you can try to use `boost::enable_shared_from_this`, which will allow you to retrieve shared pointer of an object from its own function. Then you don't have to construct another FirstStepBase object. 
You can take a look here [boost_shared_from_this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/smart_ptr/enable_shared_from_this.html)

Comment: C++11 has [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), no need for Boost.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot type-cast a raw object pointer directly to a `std::shared_ptr`.

What you can do, though, is derive `FirstStepBase` from [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), and then `FirstStepBase` can call [`shared_from_this()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) when needed, eg:

```
class FirstStepBase : public std::enable_shared_from_this<FirstStepBase>, public IFirstStep // Jobs common to all FirstStep's
{
    ...
    void correctSettings()
    {
        ...
        auto smartPtr = shared_from_this(); // <-- here
        SecondStep secondStep(smartPtr);
        ...
    }
};
```

This only works if the `FirstStep...` object is being managed by a `std::shared_ptr` to begin with, so make sure you always use `std::shared_ptr` when creating your `FirstStep...` objects.

On the other hand, if `SecondStep` is not meant to outlive its associated `FirstStep...` object, then there is no reason to pass it a `std::shared_ptr<IFirstStep>` to begin with, just pass it a raw `IFirstStep*` pointer instead:

```
class SecondStep
{
private:
    IFirstStep *m_firstStep;
public:
    SecondStep(IFirstStep *firstStep) : m_firstStep(firstStep) {}
    ...
};
```

Passing a `std::shared_ptr` only makes sense if `SecondStep` outlives all `FirstStep...` references and needs to keep the object alive.

Comment: Worth noting, when using the `enable_shared_from_this` construct, it is vital the underlying object is actually managed by a `std::shared_ptr` paradigm from the outset.  Regardless, this is a *very* handy feature and I've used it many times.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I was actually in the middle of writing that note when you posted your comment.

Comment: Thank you. What you suggested works. I presume I now have to make sure that all uses of FirstStep's instantiate it as 'std::make_shared' rather than raw objects. Is this what you mean in the last comment?

Comment: @R.Cronneberg yes, exactly.

Comment: Remy Lebeau, @WhozCraig thank you for your kind explanations.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is casted as a shared pointer, but in this case isn't it the raw pointer